# "ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT" when selecting from aliased subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Getting this error from running this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 
    T.Number,
    T.LastName, 
    T.FirstName
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 1700 -- 100 * (mean avg # site per PI + 3sd)
        PI.Number,  
        PI.LastName, 
        PI.FirstName
    FROM
        Sites S
    INNER JOIN  
        PI
    ON
        S.PI = PI.Number
    INNER JOIN 
        Protocol P 
    ON 
        PI.ProtocolNumber = P.ProtocolNumber
    INNER JOIN 
        ProductMaster PM 
    ON 
        PA.productcode = PM.productcode
    WHERE
        -- predicates
) T     
ORDER BY
    T.LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

I'm not sure why this isn't working. I've got the last name in the select list. What am I missing?

Comment: `T.LastName` is not `T.LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`

Comment: @juergend how do I specify the collation on the `order by` then?  Do I just need to collate on the `select distinct` the same way?

Comment: Why not just `select T.LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI ... order by T.LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to put the collation in the `select:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 100 T.Number, T.LastName COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI, T.FirstName
```

This is a rather insignificant change *unless* you have a case sensitive collation and you want to see the duplicates.

If so, then use `GROUP BY` and `LOWER()` (or `UPPER()`):

```
SELECT TOP 100 T.Number, T.LastName, T.FirstName
FROM (SELECT TOP 1700 -- 100 * (mean avg # site per PI + 3sd)
             PI.Number,  PI.LastName, PI.FirstName
      FROM Sites S INNER JOIN  
           PI
           ON S.PI = PI.Number INNER JOIN 
           Protocol P
           ON PI.ProtocolNumber = P.ProtocolNumberINNER JOIN 
           ProductMaster PM 
           ON PA.productcode = PM.productcode
      WHERE -- predicates
     ) T 
GROUP BY T.Number, T.LastName T.FirstName 
ORDER BY MAX(lower(T.LastName));
```